# Why $dataset.tables[0] powershell is null when i fill data from oracle?

Tags: oracle, powershell

I have a problem right here, my code is below:

```
# Load the good assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\oracle\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
# Path to file
$path = "C:\Portal-Statistics\2018\Portalrooms.xlsx"
# Open the Excel document and pull in the 'Play' worksheet
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
$page = '_4_docexchange'
$ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}
# Delete the current contents of the page
$ws.Cells.Clear() | Out-Null
#Connection string
$compConStr2 = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=38370)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=server_name)));User Id=userID;Password=pasword;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"
# Query database
$qry4 = "query database"
# 1st Connection
$oraConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($compConStr2)
$oraConn.Open()
## Export XLSX
$cmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry4,$oraConn)
$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da.Fill($dt) | Out-Null
# Close connection
$oraConn.Close()
$docexList = $dt.Tables[0]
#echo $docexList.Length
$docexList | Export-CSV customers_with_orders.csv
```

When I export to `.csv` file , my error is `$docexList` is null. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I always troubleshoot NULL value errors with `Write-Host` lines that output my relevant variables step by step, from top to bottom. I'd start by checking:

```
if ($cmd -eq $Null) {
    Write-Host "Value is null."
} Else {
    Write-Host "Value is NOT null."
}
```

If it isn't then move down the script to $da, $dt, ... and change `if (...)` accordingly. Eventually you'll find which line returns the null value. When you've found the line it's probably down to a syntax error or a logic mistake somewhere.

Also, on this line `$da.Fill($dt) | Out-Null` , you could try to remove the `| Out-Null`. I know it's there to remove the annoying number that it prints, but i seem to vaguely remember i also had an issue once with it a while back. It's worth a shot.